# AD User logon script on custom server

Tags: active-directory, logon-scripts

Is it possible to run user logon script stored on a specific machine in domain, without using GPO?
I tried to set logon script for AD user as `\\machine.domain.local\share\script.bat` or `cmd /k \\machine.domain.local\share\script.bat` but it doesn't work.
there are no sessions at `fsmgmt` on script-storage-machine when user log in
`eventvwr` checked - no related events

Answer (score 1):

User Logon Script attribute does not support absolute UNC paths. It also does not support CMD commands. The way it works, it will look for the script in NETLOGON share and try to run it.

If you really need to keep your scripts on non-DC server, just put a launcher script to your NETLOGON share. The launcher script can call another script located anywhere

Launcher script example

```
@echo off
call \\machine.domain.local\share\script.bat
```